# What is causing my output to be so messy?

Tags: java, android, c, sockets, sensors

I am currently reading sensor values from an android device, and streaming them to a pc client connected.

[image]

```
bzero(buffer,256);

//fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
while(1){   
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
   sleep(1);
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
close(sockfd);
return 0;}
```

Code for the PC client that outputs the data.

```
while(!stopFlag){
    try {
       out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())), true);

      //  out.printf(String.valueOf(accel[0]),accel[1],accel[2]);
        out.printf(String.valueOf(d.format(accel[0]))+"   "+String.valueOf(d.format(accel[1]))+"  "+String.valueOf(d.format(accel[2])) + " Accelerometer   " + "\n");
        out.printf(String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[0]))+"   "+String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[1]))+"  "+String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[2]))+ " Gyroscope   " + "\n");
        out.printf(String.valueOf(d.format(magnet[0]))+"   "+String.valueOf(d.format(magnet[1]))+"  "+String.valueOf(d.format(magnet[2]))+" Magnetometer   "+ "\n\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code Snippet of sensor values being sent.

1. How would I fix this or what's a cleaner method to output the data? [SOLVED]
2. Also how do I write the output as a csv formatted file. I've looked around but still not too sure how to read my sensor values, since I have a 4x4, being the sensor values and name of the sensor as seen in the image above.
3. If I were to add a delay/sleep function on the client side, after closing the sockets on the application side, the client would still show incoming values, any ideas on why ?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Regards

Comment: In your thoughts, what does "messy" mean?

Comment: Everything I scribbled in red. But stuff like text/values spilling onto the next line.

Comment: @ Roger , I removed the new line and it worked, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roger has provided me with correct answer, not sure where his post is now though.

Removing the \n (new line) fixed the issue, data now doesn't flow to next line.